# iPhone app with UIWebView

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

I have a doubt in developing apps for iphone,
Can I develop authentication page(with secure login id and pwd) through which I can load my webcontent.

Does apple allow applications having login credentials or not?
Can anyone please let me know this.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not? All apps that access external services like Twitter, Facebook, LiveJournal etc. have to login to these services.

You will need to provide a demo account, so Apple staff can test it. *(thanks [texmex5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787536/iphone-app-with-uiwebview/2787558#2787558) about reminder)*

Comment: Thank you... I have one more doubt, Is there any official apple document which gives all the rules/guidelines (Except UIGuidelines) to follow while developing the application so that AppStore will not reject the application?

Comment: 1) The official document is SDK agreement you have signed (did you?). 2) Also is useful to follow [News and Announcements](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/), sometimes Apple publishes there tips regarding approval process. 3) Also I have found interesting "blog" called [App Rejections](http://apprejections.com/), I hope they will continue it.

Answer (score 1):

Apple definitely allows applications that need secure login before using the app. Only thing is that you need to provide Apple demo accounts for their review process.

Comment: Thank you... I have one more doubt, Is there any official apple document which gives all the rules/guidelines (Except UIGuidelines) to follow while developing the application so that AppStore will not reject the application?

Comment: Yes, it is a good point about demo account you need to provide.